# Merging two features and deleting original two in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: merge, arcgis-pro

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

I am currently working on a city's water main system. The way the mains were input into the system they are in tiny pieces.  I want to merge them together so that they run from valve to valve.  I am using the merge tool to merge the pieces of pipe together.  The end result however, gives me 3 mains (the two originals that I merged, and the newly merged one).

How do I merge two features together and just end with the one newly merged feature?

Comment: Have you looked at the instructions on this [page](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/editing/merge-features-into-one-feature.htm)?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the dissolve tool on a unique ID field each pipe belongs to, that will create a new dataset of just the dissolved features.